# Paypal form integration with wordpress registration form without plugin

Tags: php, user-registration, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal integration with one of the wordpress registration forms in my site.

The user visits the registration page and fills out his details, like first name, last name, username, password, age, etc.
Then on clicking submit button, he navigates to the paypal site, pays some amount like 5$ and after successful payment, user will be added to a custom role.

Comment: Why "without plugin" ? The task you are describing is not trivial – and there is a number of plugins that basically do what you describe for example "PaidMembershipPro"

Comment: Thank You So much for your reply.
This is the custom registration form and there are lot of customize fields. Paidmembershippro or these kind of plugins do not have the facilities to add that's why I am not using any plugin.